# How does one enable the developer console in Safari for Outlook Add-in Dialog API?

Tags: outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins, outlook-for-mac

I am working on an add-in that is failing to load scripts via the Dialog API.

The template from the HTML renders correctly in the Dialog. If I render the template in the main `TaskPane`, both the HTML and the scripts execute correctly.

I can see the console logs in the `TaskPane`, but the Dialog seems to be a bit of a black box. There's no logs, network, or DOM info that I can see. Is there a way to enable the Safari console for the Dialog?

**** UPDATED: ADDED GIF ****

(the gif slows down the flashing of the screen, but this what happens when attempting to open the inspector in the Dialog)
[image]

Comment: Are you settings [displayInIframe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.dialogoptions?view=office-js#displayiniframe) to true or false? If the IFrame is set to false (default), the launched window will be a separate instance than the main window of OWA, and you should open a second debugger after selecting the launched window.

Comment: As to the general issue of scripts failing: Does the script fail if you use other browsers? Are you able to open the debugger for the launched dialog in another browser and see any error messages?

Comment: Thanks for the note. I am able to correctly execute the scripts on Chrome, Firefox, as well as the main TaskPane. It is only when loading it in the Dialog API that the scripts silently fail.

Comment: To help us understand the issue better, are you running the Outlook addin in Outlook for Mac or the web version?  Is the gif showing the dialog opened from dialog API?

Comment: Yes, Outlook for Mac (more context [here](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/275#issue-371641920)). I also stripped the dialog of everything but a couple simple HTML tags + the Office API script, and it has the same behavior.